# Three.js - What is PlaneBufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

What is PlaneBufferGeometry exactly and how it is different from PlaneGeometry? (r69)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`PlaneBufferGeometry` is a low memory alternative for [`PlaneGeometry`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/PlaneGeometry). the object itself differs in a lot of ways. for instance, the vertices are located in PlaneBufferGeometry are located in `PlaneBufferGeometry.attributes.position` instead of `PlaneGeometry.vertices`

you can take a quick look in the browser console to figure out more differences, but as far as i understand, since the vertices are usually spaced on a uniform distance (`X` and `Y`) from each other, only the heights (`Z`) need to be given to position a vertex.

Comment: Even though the x,y coordinates are already given with a PlaneGeometry or a PlaneBufferGeometry, they are still part of the data representation per vertex, and can still be modified.

Answer (score 11):

The main differences are between [Geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry) and [BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry).

Geometry is a "user-friendly", object-oriented data structure, whereas BufferGeometry is a data structure that maps more directly to how the data is used in the shader program. BufferGeometry is faster and requires less memory, but Geometry is in some ways more flexible, and certain operations can be done with greater ease.

I have very little experience with Geometry, as I have found that BufferGeometry does the job in most cases. It is useful to learn, and work with, the actual data structures that are used by the shaders.

In the case of a PlaneBufferGeometry, you can access the vertex positions like this:

```
let pos = geometry.getAttribute("position");
let pa = pos.array;
```

Then set z values like this:

```
var hVerts = geometry.heightSegments + 1;
var wVerts = geometry.widthSegments + 1;
for (let j = 0; j < hVerts; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < wVerts; i++) {
                            //+0 is x, +1 is y.
        pa[3*(j*wVerts+i)+2] = Math.random();
    }
}
pos.needsUpdate = true;
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Randomness is just an example. You could also (another e.g.) plot a function of x,y, if you `let x = pa[3*(j*wVerts+i)];` and `let y = pa[3*(j*wVerts+i)+1];` in the inner loop. For a small performance benefit in the PlaneBufferGeometry case, `let y = (0.5-j/(hVerts-1))*geometry.height` in the outer loop instead.

`geometry.computeVertexNormals();` is recommended if your material uses normals and you haven't calculated more accurate normals analytically. If you don't supply or compute normals, the material will use the default plane normals which all point straight out of the original plane.

Note that the number of vertices along a dimension is one more than the number of segments along the same dimension.

Note also that (counterintuitively) the y values are flipped with respect to the j indices: `vertices.push( x, - y, 0 );` ([source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/93e72ba7b24958ddb0652bd33171edd14ed2d693/src/geometries/PlaneGeometry.js#L82))

Comment: is the `+1` neessary in `widthSegments + 1`?  This would skip the first row, wouldn't it?

Comment: Assuming you mean this line:
pa[3*(j*(geometry.widthSegments+1)+i)+2] = Math.random();
when j is 0, the first row will be iterated.

Comment: Nice and useful! Perhaps, it is better to add why +1 logic i used for the loop and the calculation. To produce N segments, you need N+1 vertices. So actual number of vertices is always 1 more than number of segments.